# MySQL: Case not evaluating correctly. Where did I went wrong?

Tags: mysql, search-engine

This is the query I am executing to search for the autocomplete function for keyword "sector 2"

```
SELECT display_text,token, relevancy , 
(CASE token 
    WHEN token = 'sector' THEN relevancy*1000 
    WHEN token = '2' THEN relevancy*1000 
    ELSE relevancy / 100 
END) as real_relevancy 
FROM location_search WHERE display_text LIKE '%sector%' AND display_text LIKE '%2%' 
ORDER BY real_relevancy DESC
```

The table have five fields: id , area_id, display_text, token and relevancy. 
display text is what i want to show in auto complete search result. And token contains the display text split by spaces.

like for a display text "Sector 2 Noida" there will be 3 entries in the table

```
id    |  area_id | display_text    | token  | relevancy
6     |   234    | Sector 2 Noida  | sector | 441
7     |   234    | Sector 2 Noida  | 2      | 986
8     |   234    | sector 2 Noida  | noida  | 660
```

And similarly for all other display areas. Its pretty much clear by the query what I am trying to do here, that is getting more relevant results on the top.

The problem is that the first case evaluates true and is execulted in random cases where token is niether sector nor 2.

Like the first reult in resultset is

```
display_text                    |   token   |  relevancy   |  real_relevancy
Sector 29 - Powergrid , Gurgaon | Powergrid |  789         |  789000
```

Why is it happening. WHere did I go wrong with the query? Probably m doing some silly mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried few things and modified the case condition from token = 'sector' to just 'sector' ... its working now.

So the new query looks like this :

```
SELECT display_text,token, relevancy , 
(CASE token 
    WHEN 'sector' THEN relevancy*1000 
    WHEN '2' THEN relevancy*1000 
    ELSE relevancy / 100 
END) as real_relevancy 
FROM location_search WHERE display_text LIKE '%sector%' AND display_text LIKE '%2%' 
ORDER BY real_relevancy DESC
```

Silly mistake indeed.